# Disable Bios memory scramble fixes ram issue

Tags: memory, bios, troubleshooting, zfs, integrated-graphics

I am looking for advice on an issue.

TL:DR
Problem: ram causing screen flickering
Solution: disable memory scramble in bios fixes
Question: is the ram stick corrupted or is this a buggy vbios? Am I safe to use it for data integrity?

Long version:
I have two sticks of gskill fc3-10666cld9 with one that has screen flickering issues with the igpu on the 4460s cpu. The flickering appears as green pixels in small fine line streaks across my zfs server terminal. I have run Memtest for short periods without errors. I have tried many options to resolve, such as: relaxed timings, decrease tclk, increase shared vram, increase gpu voltage, decrease power mgmt. I have disabled monitor PSR. I have also used the ram in a different board with different monitors and cables (but same cpu) with continued green screen flickering.

*The only solution that resolves this is to disable memory scramble.*

This is weird, as memory scramble’s purpose is to decrease electronic noise, improve errors, etc. I’m not to worried about the exploits it resolves.

My question is, since this is a zfs machine of archives, is this ram corrupt? Will disabling memory scramble silence an underlying issue? Will this lead to write errors that occur outside of zfs checksum? Can I use it without worry?

Thanks to all!

Comment: Sounds like the memory is starting to fail, and since the iGPU uses reserved system memory to function and is being used for the display, you see flickering